# Do axon state-based aggregates have a way of specifying @CreatedDate and @LastModifiedDate?

Tags: axon

When creating an Axon JPA state-based aggregate is there a way to mark certain fields as being the @CreatedDate and @LastModifiedDate (as is possible with spring data jpa)?

In other words does Axon have the functionality where if any state of the aggregate is changed then axon automatically updates the `@LastModifiedDate` without us having to repeat it in every `@CommandHandler`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [@CommandHandlerInterceptor](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/messaging-concepts/message-intercepting#commandhandlerinterceptor-annotation) inside your aggregate to intercept all commands and set 
*lastModifiedDate* field.

```
@CommandHandlerInterceptor
public Object intercept(Object myCommand, InterceptorChain interceptorChain) throws Exception {

   this.lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();

   return interceptorChain.proceed();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper solution would be to implement Axon's `HandlerEnhancerDefinition` interface to update these fields. This way you can grab the same timestamp (`Instant`) from the event that gets persisted in the event store and use that on your state-stored aggregate to make them match.

I wrote a blog post with a working example with a detailed explaination how to do this: https://michael.jeszenka.com/automatically-updating-timestamp-fields-for-axon-state-stored-aggregates/

Essentially, you will need to implement the `wrapHandler()` method to specify which types of event handlers you want to wrap with your enhancer. Then you will need to define a wrapper class to execute your desired behavior, which in our case is automatically handling the timestamps of the state-stored aggregate. This wrapper class will need to implement the `Object handle(Message<?> message, T target)` method which will allow us to grab the event timestamp from the meta data and use it to set the state-stored aggregate fields.